# How to calculate sum of the years into a new column for Current to previouse years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012,
How can I achieve following(Table 2) output from table 1 with sql script/tsql?

Table 1 :Current scenario

```
--------------------------------------------------
  Year  ReferredEachYear    ActiveEachYear  
--------------------------------------------------
  2014  297                  179          
  2013  321                  144          
  2012  354                  123          
  2011  317                  90           
  2010  292                  72           
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2 : Expected OutPut

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Year  ReferredEachYear    ActiveEachYear  TotalActiveInSystem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2014  297                      179          608
  2013  321                      144          429 
  2012  354                      123          285
  2011  317                      90           162
  2010  292                      72           72 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Changed sql-server-2008 to sql-server-2012 because the question explicitly states the OP is using 2012 (and it makes a difference to the answer).

Comment: How TotalActiveInSystem is calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use the cumulative sum function:

```
select cs.*,
       sum(cs.ActiveEachYear) over (order by cs.[year]) as TotalActiveInSystem
from CurrentScenario cs
order by cs.[year] desc;
```

This function is not available in earlier versions of SQL Server. You would have to use some other method in those versions (I would use a correlated subquery).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT T.Year,
       T.ReferredEachYear
       T.ActiveEachYear
       (SELECT SUM(ActiveEachYear) FROM YourTable WHERE YourTable.Year <= t.Year) AS TotalActiveinSystem
FROM yourTable T
```

Comment: Why did I get the thumbs down?

Comment: I assume it was just a serial downvoter, because my answer was also downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Gordon already specified, in SQL Server 2012 you can use cumulative sum function. To make it easier to understand the query can be rewritten as follows.

```
SELECT cs.*
       ,SUM(cs.ActiveEachYear) OVER 
       ( ORDER BY cs.[year] 
            ROWS BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS TotalActiveInSystem
    FROM CurrentScenario cs
    ORDER BY cs.[year] DESC;
```

`ROWS BETWEEN  UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` this statement is referred to as window framing. This query and one in @Gordon's answer will produce same results. When you only specify `ORDER BY` you are implicitly defining the window frame for the calculation.

By using framing definition you can limit rows that are affected by operation.

Entire documentation on `OVER()` clause http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx